# How to create a point table from a remote csv file?

Tags: postgis, sql, point, csv

The current approach that I am using to load a csv file into a PostGIS enabled database on a server is the following:

```
-- create table
CREATE TABLE points(
 id int, 
 lat double precision,
 lng double precision 
);

-- copy data from csv with headers
COPY points (id, lat, lng)
FROM '/home/mydata.csv'
WITH 
    DELIMITER AS ',' 
    CSV HEADER ;

-- Add point geometry column to table
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'points', 'geom', 900913, 'POINT', 2);

-- Populate column with point geometries
update points set geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 900913);

-- Create a spatial index on points
CREATE INDEX idx_points ON points USING GIST (geom);
```

Although this creates a table with point geometries, there appear to be some restrictions when using the `COPY` command as you need to be a superuser. Also, I can't figure out how to upload a csv file from my laptop to the server using this approach (I need to transfer the file using ftp and then run the script).

Is there another strategy that I should be considering for generating a table with point geometries from a csv? I want to perform this entire process in PostGIS/SQL.

Comment: As far as I know, your only way to load data is using copy or executing an sql script. Since you only have a csv and don't want to preprocess is to sql, you're limited to copy. And copy only works on local files. So you're stuck ... but maybe somebody else knows a trick.

Comment: Preprocessing to SQL could be ok; what would that involve?

Comment: How about creating a Python script that runs on your laptop, reads the CSV, connects to the remote database and inserts the data?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. Is it possible to use `COPY` on that command, or would it need to be `INSERT` ?

Comment: That would be inserts.

Comment: As of today, ogr2ogr is the best option to insert CSV to postgres db https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423980/importing-a-csv-inside-postgresql-with-ogr2ogr-through-a-pipe

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe from STDIN to COPY from a client.  If you're using psql...

```
cat myfile.csv | psql -c "COPY mytable(col1, col2, col3) FROM stdin"
```