# Importing a CSV inside PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr through a pipe

Tags: ogr2ogr, bash

I can successfully import a CSV file inside PostgreSQL with the following command line:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=dbname" \
        -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lng -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat \
        -nlt GEOMETRY \
        -nln "layer_name" \
         myfile.csv
```

---

I'd like to use the `paste` command to join two different CSV files while importing them... Let's say I have a file called `file1.csv` as the following:

```
header1,header2
random value1,random value2
random value3,random value4
```

And I also have a file called `file2.csv`:

```
lng,lat
-46.627827621996,-23.6298094689846
-46.627827621996,-23.6298094689846
```

If I use the command `paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv` I'll get the following result on `stdout`:

```
header1,header2,lng,lat
random value1,random value2,-46.627827621996,-23.6298094689846
random value3,random value4,-46.627827621996,-23.6298094689846
```

---

The `paste` command works perfectly fine. I'd like to import its `stdout` result in PostgreSQL without storing this result on a temporary file (That means that using  `paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv > tmpFile.csv` and then using my first sample of functional code wouldn't be the ideal solution for me). On [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/122086), I see that it's possible to use `/vsistdin/` to make `ogr2ogr` read from pipes. So I tried the following:

```bsh
paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv | ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=dbname" \
        -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lng -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat \
        -nlt GEOMETRY \
        -nln "layer_name" \
         /vsistdin/
```

However, this line returns me the error `Unable to open datasource /vsistdin/ with the following drivers.`. What's wrong with the way I'm trying to use `/vsistdin/`? Is there any alternative way of doing it with `ogr2ogr` in a way that I don't need to store the result of the `paste` command inside a temporary file?

Comment: Please edit your question to include example data and header (as text) for file1.csv and file2.csv

Comment: PostGIS is a database extension that supports `geometry` and `geography` types in PostgreSQL databases. Datasets are not stored "inside PostGIS", but can be stored "with PostGIS" or "using PostGIS".

Comment: @user2856 I've edited it now... In practice, it'd be the same as executing `cat file.csv | ogr2ogr ...` (considering `file.csv` is a valid CSV file for importing). The issue I have in this question is more related to how to make `ogr2ogr` read the CSV that's coming from the pipe, the `paste` command is working fine and there're no issues with it.

Comment: Thanks @raylight, needed that example data to make you weren't `paste`ing (join) when you should have been `cat`ing (append below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `CSV:` prefix, i.e. `CSV:/vsistdin/`

From the [documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html):

> For files structured as CSV, but not ending with .CSV extension, the ‘CSV:’ prefix can be added before the filename to force loading by the CSV driver.

```
paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv | ogrinfo /vsistdin/
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/vsistdin/' with the following drivers.
```

But with the CSV prefix:

```
paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv | ogrinfo CSV:/vsistdin/
INFO: Open of `CSV:/vsistdin/'
      using driver `CSV' successful.
```

Comment: Thanks... As a side note, when we're importing CSV files it doesn't work if the file name doesn't finish with `.csv`... So, this prefix solution with `CSV:` works not only with pipes but also when I have a file without  `.csv` in its name.

Comment: Yes, that's always been the case as far back as I can remember (actually was introduced in GDAL 1.8.0)